# How to compare 2 hashes and findout how many nested hashes have changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

From comparing one hash to another I need to get the number of nested hashes that have changed

```
 hash1 = {"0"=>{"value"=>"value", "id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"value"=>"value1", "id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"value"=>"", "id"=>"3"}}

 hash2 = {"0"=>{"value"=>"value", "id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"value"=>"random", "id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"value"=>"seven", "id"=>"3"}}
```

The value in the key `value` will be the only thing that changes. From comparing the 2 hashes above you can see there are nested hashes that have changed

```
"1"=>{"value"=>"value1", "id"=>"2"},
```

to

```
"1"=>{"value"=>"random", "id"=>"2"}
```

and

```
"2"=>{"value"=>"", "id"=>"3"}
```

to

```
"2"=>{"value"=>"seven", "id"=>"3"}
```

I'm not sure how to compare the 2 hashes like this and findout the number of nested hashes that have changed between the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do `hash1.to_a - hash2.to_a` to obtain the differences

Comment: Tried your solution and it works. To find out the number of nested hashes we will add `.length` to the result: `(hash1.to_a - hash2.to_a).length`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see I missed, "The value in the key value will be the only thing that changes." My answer permits the values of keys other than `"value"` to change. I will leave my answer should the OP or any readers be interested in that question as well.

Here are three ways you could do that.

*Step through either hash and count differences*

```
hash1.reduce(0) { |count,(k,v)| count + ((hash2[k]["value"]==v["value"]) ? 0 : 1) }
  #=> 2
```

*Use `Hash#merge`*

This method uses the form of Hash#merge that employs a block to determine the value when a key is present in both hashes being merged. I'm not actually using the block for its intended purpose, but am merely incrementing `count` when two values are equal.

```
count = 0
hash1.merge(hash2) { |_,v1,v2| count += 1 unless v1["value"] == v2["value"] }
count
  #=> 2
```

*Get keys, pull values, zip them, sum the numbers of differences*

```
keys = hash1.keys
  #=> ["0", "1", "2"]
hash1.values_at(*keys).zip(hash2.values_at(*keys)).reduce(0) { |count,(v1,v2)|
  count + ((v1["value"] == v2["value"]) ? 0 : 1) }
  #=> 2
```

None of these methods requires the keys to be ordered the same in both hashes.

Answer (score 0):

In simple solution, I recommend you to iterate each key and compare the nested hash within the value of two hash.
As you said that the keys of two hash are similar, this solution should be suitable:

```
count = 0    
hash1.keys.each do
  count = count + 1 if hash1[key] != hash2[key]
end
# p count
```